# What is the standard Database TABLE design for an ACL?

Tags: database-design, acl

I wish to build an ACL for an application, and I was wondering if there was a standard database schema design for this?

Answer (score 4):

If it suits your needs to use *Role-Based Security* as the model for your ACL, then you can use the model I described in the answer to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12046/what-is-a-basic-model-for-making-a-database-with-users-and-groups/12107#12107).  If role-based security won't work for you as a model, is there a particular security model you had in mind?